# "large text" option in Android device make my text in app bigger with ionic/cordova

Tags: css, cordova, ionic-framework, dpi

I created a beautiful app for my ios device. I tried it on my android device, and i saw that my text was bigger then iOS device. I found the problem is the "large text" option actived on my device. How can i resolve the problem of the big text on ionic/cordova app with this option enabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use this plugin: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-mobile-accessibility

Then add the following to your `$ionicPlatform.ready` callback:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function(){
    if($window.MobileAccessibility){
        $window.MobileAccessibility.usePreferredTextZoom(false);
    }
});
```

This will ignore the text zoom set in accessibility options on a device.

Comment: I tried this and this is working in some android devices and not working for some devices. Please advice it.